# How do I select all nodes using XPath 'matches' in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, regex, xpath

I know that a similar question may exist, but I can't find the answers how to solve the problem with using `regex` in `XPath` string in the `XmlNode.SelectNodes` method in `C#`.

I need to select all nodes where an attribute value matches with `regex`. I'm trying to use `matches` function, like this:

```
filtered_nodes = xml_node.SelectNodes("./*[matches(@Name, '*')]");
```

but anyway I get the `System.Xml.XPath.XPathException`.

I'm using `MS VS 2012` with `XPath 2.0` (at least I think so).

How to use `matches` in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has no support for XPath 2.0 or XQuery 1.0 where you have a `matches` function. Either use a third party library like XmlPrime, if you want to use XPath 2.0 or XQuery 1.0, or use LINQ to XML.

The expression `./*[matches(@Name, '*')]` might be expressed in XPath 1.0 as `./*[contains(@Name, '*')]`, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Actually, '*' is not a legal regular expression in XPath: it needs to be written `\*`.